# Durbin watson tset for negative binomial regression

Tags: durbin-watson-test

I have count data as a dependent variables in my analysis. So, I am using a negative binomial regression model due to over-dispersion of data. Can I use and publish the Durbin-watson statistics for this model in my thesis?. Since the internet says DW statistics checks for autocorrelation in the case of OLS regression, can I also use it for the negative binomial model? Please help!

Comment: Do you have sequential data, like time series, that could be autocorrelated?

Comment: I have likert scale, Firm size and team member numbers, dichotomous , EFA extracted factor scores data. So I need not use. Correct?

Comment: If your data *can't* be autocorrelated because it is not sequential, then Durbin-Watson answers a question *you do not have*. But "firm size" sounds like it could be time series.

Comment: Thanks so much. I better not use it as I will not be able to justify its applicability.

Comment: @StephanKolassa In my campaign (surely futile) to reduce the number of questions without answers, I wonder if you want to make your two comments into one answer?

Comment: @PeterFlom: I have a soft spot for noble heroes fighting against great odds, so I posted an answer.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks! CV has a very low proportion of answered questions, compared to other sites. One reason is that a lot of people write comments that are, essentially, answers; the OP says something like "oh, of course" and then the questions sits there, answered, but not.

Answer (score 2):

The [Durbin-Watson test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic) detects autocorrelation in residuals from a model - specifically, autocorrelation at lag 1. If your data are not sequential, such as time series, they cannot be autocorrelated, so the Durbin-Watson test would give you an answer to an irrelevant question. (Actually, without a sequential ordering in observations, you would not be able to calculate the test statistic in the first place.)

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!